# Docker-compose: --env-file parameter doesn't work

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm having a perplexing issue building container and passing in environment variables using docker-compose.  Everything works fine when I specify `env_file` in the yaml, but it won't work from the command line (one level up from the project, see tree at bottom).

The following *docker-compose.yml* works fine when running `docker-compose up --build`.  Environment variables contained in `.env.prod` are passed into the container as expected.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  stockupdater:
    image: user/projectname
    container_name: projectname
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - ./MyProject/.config/.env.prod
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```

If I modify the yaml to **remove** the `env_file` section and specify it on the command line as follows, none of the variables in .env.prod get passed to the container:

```
docker-compose --env-file ./MyProject/.config/.env.prod up --build
```

I have also tried moving `.env.prod` to the top level, which also doesn't work.  There are no warnings or errors.

Contents of `.env.prod`:

```
CONNECTIONSTRINGS__MYCONTEXT=blahblahblah
TZ=America/Los_Angeles
DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT=Production
```

Directory tree is as follows:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── .dockerignore
├── MyProject
│ ├── appsettings.Development.json
│ ├── appsettings.json
│ ├── .config
│ │ ├── .env.dev
│ │ └── .env.prod
│ ├── Program.cs
│ └── MyProject.csproj
└── MyProject.sln
```

What am I missing?  Running Ubuntu 23.04 but having the same problem on Windows 11.